# Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackexchange.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.gravatar.com/

Tags: bug, gravatar, ssl

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackexchange.com/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/...'. This content should also be
>   served over HTTPS.

I only noticed because I've enabled [HTTP Strict Transport Security in chrome](https://www.chromium.org/hsts) for SO and SE.

The issue seems to be the randomly generated gravatars in the "Top Network Askers" sidebar. Notice that the custom ones are being served properly over https.

[image: sidebar rendered screenshot]

[image: sidebar source code screenshot]

Comment: @RobertLongson actually that one was fixed, if you notice the custom gravatars are being fetched from https, it's the randomly generated default ones that are not.

Comment: It is also duped to the main "we don't support https yet" post.

Comment: @RobertLongson Gravatars are supposed to be served over https by now (stated by Nick Craver and/or Adam Lear a while back, iirc), so this may indeed be a bug, something they missed when working on this kind of  content.  Although a more likely explanation is that they haven't done this on stackexchange.com (separate codebase).